# Generic partial Index support for sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, partial-index

Along the lines of this question, [SQLAlchemy - SQLite for testing and Postgresql for development - How to port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716847/sqlalchemy-sqlite-for-testing-and-postgresql-for-development-how-to-port/2717071#2717071)

I realize, that the (above) the consensus is **don't test with a db not used in production**.

I want to abstract **partial index** support for **sqlalchemy** such that I could use either Postgres or Sqlite.

I've seen that with `PostgreSQL` I can use

```
    Index('only_one_active_invoice', 
          invoice_id, active,
          unique=True,
          postgresql_where=(active)
    ),
```

But I see that partial index is also supported in `sqlite` https://sqlite.org/partialindex.html

Is there some sort of **generic** partial index support for **sqlalchemy** with which my module could work for either postgres or sqlite databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general way, according to [doc](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/tree/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects)

You should use for sqlite

```
idx = Index('test_idx1', tbl.c.data,
            sqlite_where=and_(tbl.c.data > 5, tbl.c.data < 10))
```

and for postgres:

```
idx = Index('my_index', my_table.c.id, 
            postgresql_where=my_table.c.value > 10)
```

in your case, you can check db engine and initialize index with kwargs